# Memoization in Recursion Class JAVA

Tags: java, recursion, memoization

I have a Class which looks like this:

```
public abstract class Recursion<X, R> {

    protected Recursion<X, R> recursion = this;

    public R recurse(@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") X... xs) {
        return recursion.recurse(xs);
    }
}

private static class LongFib extends Recursion<Long, Long> {
    @Override
    public Long recurse(Long... x) {
        return x[0] <= 2 ? 1 : super.recurse(x[0] - 1) + super.recurse(x[0] - 2);
    }
}
```

and now I have to build a method which adds memoization to this method.

```
Recursion<Long, Long> fib = new LongFib();
DPified.dpIfy(fib); // after calling this method the fib Object should have Memoization implemented.
long actual = fib.recurse(92L);
```

I know how memoization is working, but I don't know how to intercept the method call. Any advice?

Comment: "Can someone give me an Idea how to solve that?" how to solve what? Also your fibonacci implementation is rather odd, what is the purpose of `Recursion<X, R>`?

Comment: Its just an example it should work for all rekursive methodes.
Add this is not mine Implementation it`s the one of my university.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, with your current design there's no way to fully implement memoization simply by passing your `Recursion` object into another method. A better way to do it would be to have `DPified` return a new `Recursion` object which has memoization enabled.

In `DPified`, you would just return a new `Recursion` which overrides the `recurse` method to implement memoization.

Because you say you know how memoization works, I will just provide the code directly. However, you will need to implement the `hash` method (as you have chosen to take an `X[]` which does not work well with Maps/Lists directly).

```
public static Recursion<X, R> dpIfy(Recursion<X, R> original) {
  return new Recursion<X, R>() {
    private Map<Long, R> memo = new HashMap<>();
    public R recurse(X... xs) {
      long hash = hash(xs);
      if (memo.containsKey(hash)) {
        return memo.get(hash);
      } else {
        memo.put(hash, original.recurse(xs));
        return memo.get(hash);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes I know how to do this, but it has to work because its a task at my university homework so there has to be an solution. And we are not allowed to change the signature of these methodes.